# Select a product from filters

Tags: mysql, sql-match-all

I have a problem with a query:

I have 3 tables:
products (id, name)
settings (id, name)
product_setting (product_id, setting_id)

for example: I would like to select only the products you have selected filters!

I do this:

```
SELECT p. *, s.id as setting
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN product_setting p2 ON (p.id = p2.product_id)
INNER JOIN settings s ON (s.id = p2.setting_id)
WHERE s.id IN (1,2)
```

but I get all products that have the 'setting' id = 1 OR id = 2.
How to get only those products that have those 'setting' (AND)?

thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*, s.id as setting
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN product_setting p2 ON (p.id = p2.product_id)
INNER JOIN settings s ON (s.id = p2.setting_id)
WHERE s.id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*)=2; // size of IN()
```

Comment: This seem is overly presumptuous of data. Consider the case where multiple settings could exist. While this is an outside issue which may be prevented, this could could easily introduce a bug if bad data were ever allowed into the system.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like over kill but...

```
SELECT p. *, s.id as setting
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN product_setting p2 ON (p.id = p2.product_id)
INNER JOIN settings s ON (s.id = p2.setting_id)
INNER JOIN settings s2 ON (s.id = p2.setting_id)
WHERE 
    s.id = 1
    AND s2.id = 2
```

Comment: s.id cannot co-exist in both 1 and 2 in single row